# What does `echo $?` mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, command, command-line-interface

I came upon the following command:

```
echo $?
```

what does that command do?

Comment: "RTFM" is and always has been a terrible answer.  If someone asks a question, answer it or ignore it.  Don't tell them they're stupid for not looking elsewhere.  Its useless at best and rude at worst.  As it happens, identifying these short little language-embedded tokens is challenging for a newcomer to the language.   Which section of TFM should he look in?  That would at least be helpful.

Comment: I'm going to put that on a tshirt!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Echoes (prints) the exit value for the previous command.

If it failed it will be different than zero (`0`).

```
$ cd ~
$ echo $?
> 0
$ cd //whatever/
> bash: cd: //whatever/: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
> 1
```

Programs exit with a status code.  Every program is unique and has a different set of failure codes, but it's universally acknowledged that `0` is the 'success' code.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Not really useful from the terminal, helpful in a script.